# how to replace ul with new ul

Tags: jquery

how do i use jquery to replace what I have in the first ul with what I have in the second ul?

```
$('li').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text()); //so far this is what I have which alerts me with all the li's text.
});
```

---

```
<ul>
   <li>apple</li>
   <li>peach</li>
```

```
<ul>
   <li>juice</li>
   <li>candy</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul').eq(0)
   .replaceWith($('ul').eq(1));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4vh9/

Comment: Almost 25k rep, and you're writing code this inefficient? -1, dude.

Comment: @MattBall -- it works, doesn't it? how would you make it more efficient? (btw rep has nothing to do with coding proficiency)

Comment: Calvin, please note that this basically says, replace first ul on page with second ul (eq is zero based). You could substitute in your own selectors if you want to be more explicit. `$('ul#first').replaceWith($('ul#second'));`

Comment: @Matt Ball: We are waiting with bated breath for your highly-efficient alternative.

Comment: Don't re-query the DOM unnecessarily, as in jfriend00's answer. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MuFa3

Answer (score 3):

To avoid evaluating selectors multiple times, you could do this:

```
var uls = $("ul");
uls.eq(0).html(uls.eq(1).html());
```

This gets a jQuery object with the list of `<ul>` elements in it.
`eq(0)` gets the first ul and sets its innerHTML to the innerHTML of the `eq(1)` second ul.

Or with a little less jQuery and perhaps a little more readability:

```
var uls = $("ul");
uls[0].innerHTML = uls[1].innerHTML;
```